# Replace standard wordpress mobile menu with a custom one

Tags: javascript, wordpress, bootstrap-4

Hi I have recently started creating a custom theme for wordpress with understrap and I want to replace the code of the original mobile menu with my own. The issue is that i can not find where the original one is saved. Does anyone have any answer for this?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

I often use file-seek to search a file.
Download theme file, and search it.

https://www.fileseek.ca/
hope this will help u

Answer (score 0):

Understrap extends WordPress' `Walker_Nav_Menu` class. You can find the Understrap's Nav Walker Class at `[theme root]/inc/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php`.

Here is a link to Understrap's Walker Class in their Git repo:
https://github.com/understrap/understrap/blob/master/inc/class-wp-bootstrap-navwalker.php

-Chris

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help guys both advaces were very useful. The solution I came up with is to create a separate php file for the modal and use the include commant into my header file so it loads up in every page and so far it works. I hope this might help anyone who phase the same problem.